# SQL Server - Convertir el procedimiento almacenado en función

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, tsql

Estoy en la creación de una función a partir de un procedimiento almacenado, ya que recien comienzo con el tema de funciones en SQL Server solicito de una orientación en la manera correcta de crearla.

El siguiente es el procedimiento almacenado el cual deseo crear la función:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SPTest]   @Anio   int,
                            @Mes    int
as
begin

Declare @AnioMes    varchar(8),
        @AnioMes6   varchar(8)

    if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
                @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -5, @AnioMes), 112 )


    SELECT year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME))*100+month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) as AnioMes
          ,DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) as FECHA_CREACION
          ,INPUTSUBJECT
          ,Case When TOWTYPE = 1 then 'T1'
                When TOWTYPE = 2 then 'T2'
                When TOWTYPE = 3 then 'T3'
                When TOWTYPE = 4 then 'T4'
                Else ''
            End as TOWTYPE
          ,[VENDNAME]
        FROM TRUCKS
        Where   year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) >= yEAR(@AnioMes6)
        and month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) <= MONTH(@AnioMes)
        AND     DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) >= '20160701'
```

Espero que alguien pueda darme un poco de orientación en como crear una función a partir de este procedimiento almacenado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego esta respuesta por que es relativamente distinta a la dada por Luis Cazares y te puede ser útil en algún caso. Conceptualmente una función "tabular" retorna una tabla que antes podremos completar con al menos un `insert`, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MiFuncion(
    @Anio   int,
    @Mes    int
) RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    Id              INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    AnioMes         INT,
    FechaCreacion   DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @AnioMes    varchar(8),
        @AnioMes6   varchar(8)

    if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
            @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -5, @AnioMes), 112 )


    INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes, FechaCreacion)
    SELECT year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME))*100+month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) as AnioMes,
        DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) as FECHA_CREACION
        FROM TRUCKS
        Where   year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) >= yEAR(@AnioMes6)
            AND month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) <= MONTH(@AnioMes)
            AND DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) >= '20160701'

    RETURN

END
```

Este ejemplo está limitado a solo dos de tus columnas, pero supongo que se entiende la idea:

(A) Defines el retorno, con una pseudo tabla en memoria:

```
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    Id              INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    AnioMes         INT,
    FechaCreacion   DATETIME,
    ...
)
```

(B) Insertas en esta tabla, la salida de tu consulta (completando las columnas que tuvieras)

```
INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes, FechaCreacion, ...)
SELECT ...
```

Comment: He definido el retorno con una tabla en memoria y he insertado en esta misma tabla la salida de mi consulta pero al ejecutar la función obtengo como error lo siguiente: `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

Comment: Estas insertando un valor en una columna entera pero no puede convertirse a ese tipo, revisa la inserción que estas haciendo, en particular las columnas INT y que valores provee tu consulta

Comment: Tienes razón, tenia mal definido el tipo de dato que estaba insertando en la columna.

Answer (score 2):

La lógica del procedimiento es muy extraña. Estás comparando años y meses por separado en vez de comparar fechas completas. También estás comparando fechas UTC con fechas locales. Para efectos prácticos, quité todo lo que no parecía tener sentido (incluyendo conversiones a tipos de datos erróneos) y me concentré en cambiar el procedimiento en una función.

Es muy importante (y básico) comprender la diferencia entre una función y un procedimiento almacenado. La función está hecha para regresar algo (un valor escalar o un conjunto de datos) mientras un procedimiento está diseñado para realizar un proceso que puede terminar el retorno de conjuntos de datos y valores pero no es necesario.

Dicho lo anterior, es importante mencionar que las funciones (especialmente las tipo tabla) con múltiples instrucciones son un problema de rendimiento que pueden generar cuellos de botella en un sistema que no se pueden corregir. Las funciones tipo tabla de una sola instrucción no tienen ese problema, por lo que presento una función de ese tipo.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[AlgunaFuncion](
    @Anio   int,
    @Mes    int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH cteAnioMes AS(
        SELECT ISNULL( DATEADD( MM, 1, DATEFROMPARTS( @Anio, @Mes, 1)), DATEDIFF( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AnioMes
    )
    SELECT year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME))*100
         +month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) as AnioMes
          ,DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) as FECHA_CREACION
          ,INPUTSUBJECT
          ,Case When TOWTYPE = 1 then 'T1'
                When TOWTYPE = 2 then 'T2'
                When TOWTYPE = 3 then 'T3'
                When TOWTYPE = 4 then 'T4'
                Else ''
            End as TOWTYPE
          ,[VENDNAME]
        FROM TRUCKS t
        JOIN cteAnioMes ON CREATEDDATETIME >= DATEADD( MM, -5, x.AnioMes)
                       AND CREATEDDATETIME < x.AnioMes
        WHERE CREATEDDATETIME >= '20160701'

GO
```